# How can manipulate redux data after dispatch it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a search screen, contain Input And TopTabs "Songs, Artists",

When I get data from API after a search I make two things

1- I setState to appear the TopTab Component "true/false"
2- dispatch an action to save Songs & Artists Data in redux store.

that works fine.

But in topTab component, as I say before I have tow tabs "songs, artists"

For example, In the Songs component, I want to manipulate the data to achieve my case so in `componentDidMount` I Map the songs array from redux and push the new data into the component state.

But it's not working fine!

At the first time, I got songs from redux as empty [] although it's saved successfully in redux store when I get data from API

So how can I handle this case to not mutate the data?

Search.js "Main screen"

```
onSearch = async () => {
    const {searchText} = this.state;
    if (searchText.length > 0) {
      this.setState({onBoarding: false}); // to appear the TopTab Component
      try {
        let response = await API.post('/search', {
          name: searchText,
        });
        let {
          data: {data},
        } = response;
        let artists = data.artists.data;
        let songs = data.traks.data;
        this.props.getResult(songs, artists);
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
}

render(){

<View style={styles.searchHeader}>
          <Input
            onChangeText={text => this.search(text)}
            value={this.state.searchText}
            onSubmitEditing={this.onSearch}
            returnKeyType="search"
          />
        </View>

        {this.state.onBoarding ? (
            <SearchBoard />
        ) : (
          <SearchTabNavigator /> // TopTabs component
        )}
}
```

SongsTab

```
...
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('props.songs', this.props.songs); // Empty [] 
        let All_tunes = [];
        if (this.props.songs?.length > 0) {
          console.log('mapping...');
          this.props.songs.map(track =>
            All_tunes.push({
              id: track.id,
              name: track.name,
              url: URL + track.sounds,
              img: URL + track.avatar,
            }),
          );
          this.setState({All_tunes});
        }
      }
...
    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      return {
        songs: state.searchResult.songs,
      };
    };
```

## Edit

I fix the issue by using `componentDidUpdate()` life cycle

> If you have any other ways tell me, please!

SongsTab

```
 manipulateSongs = arr => {
    let All_tunes = [];
    arr.map(track =>
      All_tunes.push({
        id: track.id,
        name: track.name,
        url: URL + track.sounds,
        img: URL + track.avatar,
      }),
    );
    this.setState({All_tunes});
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.songs?.length > 0) {
      this.manipulateSongs(this.props.songs);
      console.log('mapping...');
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.songs !== this.props.songs) {
      this.manipulateSongs(this.props.songs);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're referring to has to do with the way asynchronous code is handled in JavaScript (and in turn react-redux). When your component initially mounts, your redux store passes its initial state to your `SongsTab.js` component. That seems to be an empty array.

Any API call is an asynchronous action, and won't update the redux store until the promise has resolved/rejected and data has been successfully fetched. Any HTTP request takes much longer to complete than painting elements to the DOM. So your component loads with default data before being updated with the response from your API call a number of milliseconds later.

The way you've handled it with class-based components is fine. There are probably some optimizations you could add, but it should work as expected. You might even choose to render a Spinner component while you're fetching data from the API as well.

If you want a different approach using more modern React patterns, you can try and use the equivalent version with React hooks.

```
  const Songs = ({ fetchSongs, songs, ...props }) => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
      // dispatch any redux actions upon mounting
      // handle any component did update logic here as well

    }, [songs])

    // ...the rest of your component
  }
```

Here are the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for the useEffect hook.